# Google Pay AutoResolveHelper with registerForActivityResult() APIs (refactor not to use deprecated methods)

Tags: android, deprecated, onactivityresult, registerforactivityresult

Refactoring codebase by replacing deprecated `Activity.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` methods with recommended `registerForActivityResult()` APIs, but encountered that Google Pay integration with `AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(Task, Activity, int)` still uses deprecated one. Seems like documentation from Google side is not updated, maybe I missed something or for *Google* Pay we still have to use deprecated (by *Google*) methods?

Links to documentations:

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#paymentdata

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/AutoResolveHelper

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result